# Mount Google Docs as OS folder/disk

Tags: google-drive

I use Google Docs on a regular basis and, although I find it plenty usable for local formats, there are a bunch of documents not in docs format (like XSD, DTD, Microsoft Project files, ...) for which I have to download, which I really find annoying.

So, is there a way to "mount" Google Docs as a "network share", or any other OS-level architecture?

Comment: "Mount" , you can create a shared google docs and everyone can work on this account. I'm waiting google docs' offline storage with html5 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(NOTE: This answer only applies to Windows; the process may vary and/or may not be possible on other OSs.)

I have my Google Drive folder mapped as my "G:" drive, which makes navigating to and referencing my synced Drive files and folders a cinch compared to having to go through my user folder.

As Al E. mentioned in [his answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/86827/103934), you will need to download Google Drive for your PC to sync to/from a folder. Once you have that all set up, the `subst` command should do the trick as far as mapping a local folder such as your Google Drive folder as a drive. **However**, just using `subst` in the Command Prompt is only a temporary measure, as all "subst'd" drives are unmounted upon reboot.

To keep your subst'd drives between sessions, you should use [Visual Subst](http://www.ntwind.com/software/utilities/visual-subst.html), which is a simple, free, and lightweight yet highly nifty application that makes mounting local folders as drives *really* easy AND automatically remounts them at the start of a new session (if you so choose).

Answer (score 1):

You mean the [Google Drive](https://www.google.com/drive/download/) app?

Essentially, you install it on your PC/Mac (there are also apps for Android and iOS) it synchronizes a special folder on your drive (you can configure where) with the "My Drive" section of Google Drive. (It's very similar to Dropbox in this respect.)

The synchronization is two-way, of course. If you upload a file to the web interface of Google Drive, it will automagically appear on your hard drive.

Answer (score -2):

You could try Gladinet Cloud Desktop

Comment: I would have largely prefered a free solution.